# Android SMS Receiver Crash

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to capture incoming sms messages for my application. In order to do that I am using a BroadcastReceiver. I have setup permissions and a filter in the manifest file. Whenever I receive a text the application crashes, when I try to debug the program it doesn't even get to the first line of code in the receiver. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Here is the code for the receiver:

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;

import android.os.Bundle;

public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    String from = null;
    String msg = null;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          this.abortBroadcast();

            //---get the SMS message passed in---
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();   
            SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
            String str = "";            
            if (bundle != null)
            {
                //---retrieve the SMS message received---
                Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];            
                for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
                    msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);                
                    str += "SMS from " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                    from = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                    str += " :";
                    str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
                    msg = msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
                    str += "\n"; 
                }
            }        
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean the console log, or something else in the debugger? Because nothing visible in the debugger said anything other than source not found.

Comment: The Logcat, I mean. You will have to enable the logcat view first.

Comment: I have been trying a different approach but the error I keep running into is that the program is unable to instantiate the BroadcastReceiver and it claims the error is "Class not found" meaning the class is not in the apk file. What is going on??????? I have tried this on two different projects with different examples as starting points and everything works in the example, but when I try to use the broadcast receiver everything crashes!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Remove Bin & Gen File form your project  & also register this receiver in your mainfest.

```
 <receiver android:name="yourpackagename.Boot" >
            <intent-filter>

              <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_CB_RECEIVED" >
                </action>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" >
                </action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

I hope its work for you because its work for me.